# Fountains of Coins

Tags: combinatorics

A fountain is formed by starting with a row of coins, then stacking additional coins on top so that each new coin touches two in the previous row. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coins_in_a_fountain) for more detailed descriptions. If denote the number of fountains of $n$ coins as $a_n$, the series $\{a_n\}$ is given in OEIS [A005169](http://oeis.org/A005169), where also contains an interesting formula to calculate $a_n=f(n,1)$ with:
$$\begin{equation}
f(n,p)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if} \ p>n\\
1 & \text{if} \ p=n\\
\sum_{q=1}^{p+1}f(n-p,q) & \text{if} \ p<n\end{cases}
\end{equation}$$
I'd like to ask how to interpret this formula? What does $f(n,p)$ represent?

Comment: I can't get it to work out.  Typically this sort of thing comes from a recurrence, adding up the smaller fountains that make up a large one.  $f(n,p)$ could then be the number of fountains with $n$ coins and $p$ coins on the bottom layer and you sum over the ways to put $n-p$ coins into fountains above the layer.  That does not fit with $f(n,1)$ being the number we want, and I don't understand the sum.  $f(n,p)$ could be the number of ways to make $p$ fountains out of $n$ coins, which matches wanting $f(n,1)$ but I still can't make the recurrence work.

Comment: If $f(n,p)$ is the number of ways to put $n$ coins into $p$ fountains I don't see how you get a recurrence because there isn't a good way to get simpler than one fountainl